# DB2 iSeries Binary to String Error

Tags: c#, db2

I am reading DB2 iSeries data in C# using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries and am getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: A conversion error occurred converting binary to string data.
   at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.MPDataConverter.ConvertPtrToString(IntPtr pointer,
   Int32 length, UInt16 jobccsid)
```

What has me baffled is that I cannot even read the result of the query into an object like this:

```
object o = reader.GetValue(7);
```

It works fine on 99% of the records but throws this exception on those few.

What's more interesting is if I read the data using ODBC, it works fine for all records.

I've tried both of these approaches in the connection string, and they both connect successfully, but they do not resolve the conversion error:

```
iDB2ConnectionStringBuilder sb = new iDB2ConnectionStringBuilder();
sb.DataSource = "foo.com";
sb.UserID = "uid";
sb.Password = "pw";
sb.LibraryList = "LIB1";
sb.CharBitDataAsString = true;
sb.Naming = iDB2NamingConvention.SQL;

string cs = string.Format("DataSource={0};UserID={1};Password={2};" +
    "Naming={3};LibraryList={4};CharBitDataAsString=true;",
    "foo.com", "uid", "pw", "SQL", "LIB1");
```

Comment: what version of IBM i?  How is the column defined and what is actually in it?

Comment: @Charles, I unfortunately don't know the server version.  The client version is 12.  Per `syscolumns` the field is a char(10), believe it or not -- it contains the username of whoever last changed the record.

Comment: So, when you issue `reader.GetValue(7)` at a particular record, you get that exception? What is in that column when you access it via ODBC?

Comment: @mustaccio -- yes, exactly.  The error is thrown on GetValue(), and only for those few records (out of millions).  When I access the column via ODBC, the value is blank.

Comment: What does "blank" mean? A single space character? NULL? Empty string? Some non-printable character? You could try `HEX(your7thcolumn)`.

Comment: (Speculation here) It kind of sounds like an ASCII NULL issue. Do you get the same if you do `SELECT x'00' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` (or whatever the equivalent is for iSeries) ?

Comment: @mustaccio -- when I do hex(), it returns this: "00000000000000000000."  The output when I return the actual field is nothing -- no bytes (which is unusual for a char(10) -- I would expect 10 spaces), but when I do length() on the field it returns 10

Comment: Well, that is obviously an invalid username, full of binary zeroes. Typically `0x00` is interpreted as the end of string, that is, a normal program would consider the value as an empty (zero-length) string. However, `CHAR(10)` assumes there are always 10 valid characters in the column, so probably the .Net driver gets confused.

Comment: Honestly,  you should fix the data...

Comment: @Charles -- tell me about it.  Unfortunately, I don't own the data, and am not in IT.  I'm just at the tail end of this whip

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround, not a solution, but honestly without the feedback I got here I wouldn't even have this.  I realize this is less than ideal, but if anyone is backed into a corner with this problem in the future, it is *an* option.

```
SELECT
  bzaitx, bzbldt, bzanva, bzcqcd, bzgncd, bzaldt, bzabtm,
  case when hex (bzafvn) != '00000000000000000000' then bzafvn end, 
  bzagvn, bzamdt, bzactm, bzahvn,
  case when hex (bzaivn) != '00000000000000000000' then bzaivn end
FROM foo.bar
```

And for what it's worth, it has resolved the issue.

Also, as a note of interested, this impacts 90 records out of 1.3 million.